# Java: Limiting decimals from a double in output without e.g. %5.2d

Tags: java, arrays, double, decimal

I'm very (read: extremely) new to java and was going to make a table with 5 columns print out for an assignement.
The two first columns are strings, third one an int, fourth a double and fifth an int. It is three rows in total that are affected by this.
I formatted it with printf and:

```
System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s%10s%14d%20.2f%12d\n", stringOne, 
stringTwo, firstInt, stupidDouble, secondInt);
```

and

```
"%s\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%2.4f\t\t%d\n" (with the format and stuff above as well ofc).
```

But the teacher didn't want me to "hard code" the layout since it's part of learning special commands (like \t) and thus wanted me to change it and adress it in the variable itself instead.
I've been trying everything I can think of but can't get it to skip the last decimals, which are unneccesary 0's.
I wish I could've just used the numbers as a string instead, but I need it to calculate the last int with:

```
static int lastInt = (int) Math.round ( stupidDouble - firstInt )
```

What I suspect that my teacher is looking for me to do is tabs all the way like:

```
"%s\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%f\t\t%d\n"
```

But I need to double to be e.g. 1.2345 instead of 1.234500.
If it makes any difference, it's 3 different doubles (3 different rows in the table); one with 2 decimals, one with 4 and one with 5.

It would more or less save my weekend if someone could help me with this. The simplest possible solution would be much appreciated. <3

Comment: What about `String formattedDouble = String.format("%5.2f", stupidDouble);`. Your format in the `printf()` call would change to `%s\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n`.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like it doesn't want to print it in the System.printf (Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field formattedDouble), and if I change it to 
    static String formattedDouble = String.format("%5.2f", stupidDouble)
It gives me a hugh error message when I run it.

Comment: Either prefix `String formattedDouble` with `static` or make it a local variable which means define `formattedDouble` inside the method body.

Comment: Hit enter too soon. Sorry about that. Error is:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at STOP.<clinit>(STOP.java:18)

Comment: I am sorry. I was retarded and mixed up the variables. 
Now for the (I HOPE) final problem, which is more of an aestethic change.
It now uses a comma instead of period sign ("," instead of ".") in the number, which I would like to avoid. I am assuming that it is because I'm working in a different "language zone" since the Locale.ENGLISH solved this before. Is there some way to avoid this? I can't seem to find a way to make it do this when it's a formatted string.

Comment: What about `String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%5.2f", stupidDouble)`. Performing localization would be another way to cope with this but that may be overdone for an assignment.

Comment: You are my hero blafasel! I had tried that but left out the "," after Locale.ENGLISH. This assignement ought to be done now! I hope so at least. Thank you so much for your help!